# Accessing Azure Key Vault 'secrets' locally for Environment Variables - C#

Tags: c#, azure, devops, azure-keyvault

How do I access my Azure Key Vault's "secrets" **locally**, to be used as environment variables?

I have an integration test application which loads some secrets from a `Settings.runsettings` file where the secrets are currently defined as Environment Variables. My `Settings.runsettings` file currently looks like this:

```
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    .....
    <EnvironmentVariables>
      <MySecret>this needs to be removed and replaced with an Azure Key Vault secret reference</MySecret>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
  ....
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

I need to remove all secrets from source control, so the 'value' of `MySecret` needs to be replaced with a secret reference from my Azure Key Vault. I checked [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli) but it's not clear to me how exactly I'm supposed to reference my Azure Key Vault and get the value of "MySecret" for app startup in my `Settings.runsettings` file.

Comment: There are a few ways, if you want it on your startup, maybe this helps ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to remove all secrets from source control

That's the right thing to do, you are doing a great job! Secrets could be read from multiple possible sources based on your use case, like App Configuration, from Environment or in case of development environment, from Visual Studio User Secrets. However, indeed the ideal storage for secrets is the KeyVault. You can also load secrets directly from KeyVault at startup.

> how exactly I'm supposed to reference my Azure Key Vault and get the value of "MySecret" for app startup

The best way to access KeyVault from your app startup is to use `Managed Identity`, where the Managed Identity will have authorization to read from the vault. However, this works only when your app is running in Azure and it wont work in local machine development environment as there is no `Managed Identity`.

Visual Studio User Secrets is one solution for this case, however, it is not very scalable as the secrets need to be copied to each developer's local machine.

To resolve this issue, Microsoft has introduced the `AzureCliCredential` class, which will authorize with your Azure CLI identity ( the one you login with `az login` ).

So, to make things work, you have to use `ManagedIdentityCredential` when your app is running in Azure and `AzureCliCredential` when app is in development environment. To make this happen, you can use the `ChainedTokenCredential` wrapper.

```
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(
        new Uri("https://mykv.vault.azure.net"),
        new ChainedTokenCredential(
            new ManagedIdentityCredential(),
                   new AzureCliCredential()
        ));
```

When you run the app in Azure, it will use `ManagedIdentityCredential` and in development since there is no managed identity, it will fall back to `AzureCliCredential`.

Don't forget to add the NuGets:

```
dotnet add package Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets
dotnet add package Azure.Identity
```

Comment: You can also use the simpler new DefaultAzureCredential()

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the built in **User Secrets** feature in Visual Studio
(right-click on your project to activate it)

[image]

read more about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/developer-app-secrets-storage

Comment: How to you use locally the Secret Manager and on Azure the KeyVault?

Comment: The local user secret and Azure KeyVault are two separate things, but you can just add Azure Key Vault to the appliacation and it will use the values from it instead of the local user store.

Comment: Would you have an example how to configure this? I was passing the Configuration so it can be used by my Controller / passed on to other classes like below on the  
Program.cs - builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(builder.Configuration); - from there I can access the Secret Manager secrets - how would I configure this to work with Key Vault when on Azure?

Comment: SEe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-8.0 , look for the    builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(
        new Uri($"https://{builder.Configuration["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/"),
        new DefaultAzureCredential()); part

Comment: Thank you. I added using Azure.Identity at the top but it doesnt seem to know AddAzureKeyVault - using .net core 8. Any idea? Error - 'ConfigurationManager' does not contain a definition for 'AddAzureKeyVault' and no accessible extension method 'AddAzureKeyVault' accepting a first argument of type 'ConfigurationManager' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to add the NuGet package for Azure Key Vault.

Comment: The missing nuget package was Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets